React and i18next won't change language
The problem: I need to support multiple languages in my React application. When I call i18next.changeLanguage(...), nothing happens in the application. This is how the code is structured:
This is the 18next configuration. Probably have a lot of redundant properties, but I have tried adding stuff I did not have that others pointed out in their problems on this site, just to make sure I was not missing anything.
const resources = {
    sv: {
        translation: sv,
    },
    en: {
        translation: en,
    }
};

i18next
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        ns: ['translation'],
        defaultNS: 'translation',
        debug: true,
        lng: 'sv',
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        supportedLngs: ['sv', 'en'],
        resources: resources,
    });

export default i18next;

Then I have a language selector component, which is basically just a dropdown that sends the selected language to a LanguageService.
private selectLanguage(lang: string): void {
  LanguageService.setLanguage(lang);
}

The LanguageService picks up the change and propagates it to its internal subject, which will trigger its public observer (using RXJS here).
class LanguageServiceImpl {
  private languageChangedSub = new ReplaySubject<string>();
  public languageChanged$ = this.languageChangedSub.asObservable();

  public setLanguage(lang: string): void {
    i18next.changeLanguage(lang, () => {
      moment. Locale(lang);
      this.languageChangedSub.next(lang);
    });
  }
}

And finally, the App component, which is observing the language change acts on it:
LanguageService.languageChanged$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unmount.unmount$))
  .subscribe(() => this. Render());

But this has no effect whatsoever.. the language does not change.
I have even tried wrapping the App in an i18nextProvider like so:
<React.StrictMode>
  <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </I18nextProvider>
</React.StrictMode>

A lot of the examples use functional components and hooks, but I am doing this with class components because that it is how I function (pun intended), so there is probably something I am missing or not grasping in the i18next concept. Please help.
